# does "fey-lit" make sense?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I want to say a strangely-lit grove, eerily-lit in an out-of-this-world manner. Does "fey-lit" convey that meaning?

Comment: I thought it meant "campy literature."

Comment: @Joel Spolsky: The fey produce purple light.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense. The only incorrect interpretation that comes to mind is "lit by fey creatures themselves" rather than "lit in a manner suggestive of the fey". Context probably disambiguates it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can say strangely lit and eerily lit. You can say it was a feyly lit glade (though I've never heard it said). *Fey* is an adjective and so is *lit* (in its use here). You'd need an adverb to modify *lit*. That said, fey-lit does sound eerie and strange.

Comment: yeah this was my issue, using an adjective is a verb. but you can say "red-lit" and it means lit by red light, no?

Comment: In "red-lit," red would have to be used as a noun, which it is, apart from being an adjective. (An example of this kind of compound adjective is "gender-neutral".) If you wished to use this logic here, you would have to say "feyness-lit", which just wouldn't sound the same. Creative writing must be something very hard to edit.

Comment: On the other hand, you might say something like, "as shadows danced in the fey light," and still be grammatical. You'll probably know how you want to say it:-)

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider "fey-limned" for a slightly more subtle sort of glow; "fey-lit" could be thought to be fairly bright.

Comment: Beware the readers of the Baltimore Sun, who appear to find the word "limn" outrageous (http://articles.baltimoresun.com/2010-09-07/news/bs-md-limn-headline-20100907_1_headline-front-page-dictionaries). Besides, its sense of "illumination" has nothing to do with light and everything to do with manuscripts, so it's wrong in this context. It's got to be "lit", "lighted", or *maybe* "lightened".

Comment: Hm.  Perhaps I've been using this word incorrectly; I tend to use it primarily in the sense of "to outline in clear detail", which is listed as a valid definition at m-w.com, although without the suggestion of actual illumination that I have always ascribed to it.  ... I did see that Sun article a couple of days ago, though, and was quite amused by it.  :-)